# VBA Run-time error '91' : Object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am facing issue with my macro, its running smoothly from desktop however when i put same file in network drive, other users facing `Runtime error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set`.
Also let me know how to remove protected view using macro.

Need your help for below code:

In Module

```
   Sub UnhideAllSheets()
    'Unhide all sheets in workbook.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next ws
End Sub
Sub HideAllSheets()
    'Unhide all sheets in workbook.
    Call UnhideAllSheets
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, "START", vbTextCompare) = 0 _
           And InStr(1, ws.Name, "Data", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ws.Visible = xlVeryHidden
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub


Sub DRD()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Call HideAllSheets
    'If VBA.Environ("Username") = "140736TJ" Then
    'Sheets("8.Generator").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    'Sheets("8.Generator").Select

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case VBA.Environ("Username")
            Case "130349TJ", "130355TJ"
                Sheets("1.Large MCH").Visible = xlSheetVisible
                Sheets("1.Large MCH").Select
            Case "140646TJ"
                Sheets("2.Large FAB").Visible = xlSheetVisible
                Sheets("2.Large FAB").Select
            Case "130361TJ"
                Sheets("3.Blade").Visible = xlSheetVisible
                Sheets("3.Blade").Select
            Case "120243TJ"
                Sheets("4.Nozzle").Visible = xlSheetVisible
                Sheets("4.Nozzle").Select
            Case "130360TJ", "146061tc"
                Sheets("5.T.Assy").Visible = xlSheetVisible
                Sheets("5.T.Assy").Select
            Case "110206TJ"
                Sheets("6.Rotor").Visible = xlSheetVisible
                Sheets("6.Rotor").Select
            Case "120237TJ"
                Sheets("7. Control Valve").Visible = xlSheetVisible
                Sheets("7. Control Valve").Select
            Case "140736TJ", "110088TJ", "130344TJ"
                Call UnhideAllSheets
                Sheets("DRD Index Consolidation").Select
            Case "120234TJ"
                Call UnhideAllSheets
                Sheets("DRD Index Consolidation").Select
                Call StopDeleteRowCols
            Case Else
                MsgBox "ACCESS DENIED"
                ActiveWorkbook.Close
                Call ResetDeleteRowCols
        End Select
    End With

End Sub


Sub StopDeleteRowCols()
    Dim ctl As CommandBarControl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=293)
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=294)
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=296)
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=3181)
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=292)
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=3125)
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=21)
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=945)
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=4)
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl

End Sub


Sub ResetDeleteRowCols()
    Dim ctl As CommandBarControl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=293)
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=294)
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=296)
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=3181)
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=292)
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=3125)
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=21)
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=945)
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=4)
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    DRD

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is giving the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should say what line you are getting the error.  I'm sure the error comes from `Application.CommandBars.FindControlsID:=?)` not finding any controls.  To trap the error I create a method `Sub BatchEnableControls(Enable As Boolean)` to find and Enable/Disable the controls.  I also made a few other changes that will make the code easier to follow and expand.

```
Sub DRD()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Call HideAllSheets
    'If VBA.Environ("Username") = "140736TJ" Then
    'Sheets("8.Generator").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    'Sheets("8.Generator").Select


    Select Case VBA.Environ("Username")
        Case "130349TJ"
            Sheets("1.Large MCH").Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheets("1.Large MCH").Select
        Case "140646TJ"
            Sheets("2.Large FAB").Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheets("2.Large FAB").Select
        Case "130361TJ"
            Sheets("3.Blade").Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheets("3.Blade").Select
        Case "120243TJ"
            Sheets("4.Nozzle").Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheets("4.Nozzle").Select
        Case "130360TJ"
            Sheets("5.T.Assy").Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheets("5.T.Assy").Select
        Case "110206TJ"
            Sheets("6.Rotor").Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheets("6.Rotor").Select
        Case "120237TJ"
            Sheets("7. Control Valve").Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheets("7. Control Valve").Select
        Case "130355TJ"
            Sheets("1.Large MCH").Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheets("1.Large MCH").Select
        Case "146061tc"
            Sheets("5.T.Assy").Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheets("5.T.Assy").Select
        Case "140736TJ", "110088TJ", "130344TJ", "120234TJ"
            Call UnhideAllSheets
            Sheets("DRD Index Consolidation").Select

        Case "120234TJ"
            Call UnhideAllSheets
            Sheets("DRD Index Consolidation").Select
            BatchEnableControls False

        Case Else
            MsgBox "ACCESS DENIED"

            BatchEnableControls True

            ActiveWorkbook.Close

    End Select

End Sub


Sub BatchEnableControls(Enable As Boolean)

    EnableControls Enable, 293
    EnableControls Enable, 294
    EnableControls Enable, 296
    EnableControls Enable, 3181
    EnableControls Enable, 292
    EnableControls Enable, 3125
    EnableControls Enable, 21
    EnableControls Enable, 945
    EnableControls Enable, 4

End Sub

Sub EnableControls(Enable As Boolean, ControlID As Long)
    Dim ctl As CommandBarControl
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=ControlID)
        ctl.Enabled = Enable
    Next ctl

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Description & " Could not find Control ID:=& ControlID  "
    End If
    On Error GoTo zero
End Sub
```

Comment: In excel option if i enable accept all macros by default this Run-time error 91 is coming, if i disable macro and accept manually every time opening the sheet, then everything is fine. Kindly help